# Chrome Extension Opening in New Tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I developed a Chrome Extension and in my Manifest file the permissions are `"permissions": ["tabs", "storage"]`. When the app got published it shows permissions as `Replace the page you see when opening a new tab` and `Read your browsing history`

The main issue is that every time a new tab it replaces the page with my extension.

In my `background.js` file I'm only using the `tabs` API to get the current tab's url like this:

```
const getCurrentTab = async () => {
    let queryOptions = { active: true, currentWindow: true };
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);

    const recipe = await fetchParsedRecipe(tab.url);

    return recipe;
};
```

This `getCurrentTab` function gets called in both `tabs.onUpdated` and `tabs.onActivated`

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(() => {
    getCurrentTab();
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(() => {
    getCurrentTab();
});
```

How do I make sure that the extension doesn't open in the window of the new tab?[image]

Comment: Remove `chrome_url_overrides` from your manifest.json.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to replace your New Tab page with your page in your Chrome extension manifest v3. You can do the following, this will only open your HTML page when you click the browser button. And it returns the current tab URL to that page (as a query string).

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Open a new tab",
  "action": {},
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "A click to open my own tab page",
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  var newURL = chrome.runtime.getURL("tab.html");
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL + "?=" + tab.url });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggested! I was trying to use the other api so I can do my fetch in the background before the action button was clicked. @wOxxOm comment above did the trick

Although this will probably work too.